# C# Page doesn't save PDF or PPT

Tags: c#, asp.net, pdf, upload

I'm having troubles uploading files. I need users to upload ppt, pdf, doc, png, jpg etc but if i try it only saves doc and png. Anyone knows why?

```
 public void uploadFile(ACFilesModel picture, Bestanden actualiteiten)
    {
        string path = "";
        string VirPath = "";
        for (int i = 0; i < picture.Files.Count; i++)
        {
            if ((picture.Files[i] != null) && (picture.Files[i].ContentLength > 0) && (picture.Files[i].ContentLength < 2097152))
            {
                var fileName = Path.GetFileName(picture.Files[i].FileName);

                path = Path.Combine(System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath(@"/LGSite/Site/Images/" + fileName));
                picture.Files[i].SaveAs(path);
                ViewBag.path = path;
                VirPath = path.Replace(path, @"/Images/" + fileName);
                db.Bestanden.Add(new Bestanden { ContentType = VirPath, BsOmschrijving = picture.OmschrijvingBS[i], Nieuws_ID = actualiteiten.Nieuws.ID });
                db.SaveChanges();
            }
            else
            {
                ModelState.AddModelError("ContentType", "File is te groot!");
            }
        }
    }
```

hope you can help!

Comment: You are only saving files under a certain content length. Have you checked the size of the files not saving to make sure they are not being filtered by your if statement?

Comment: That was also what I thought, but that doesn't matter, the problem keeps excisting if I leave out the filter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Stupidest mistake ever.
I had to change the path. The server couldn't find the right path (because it didn't exist duh) but now it works.
Dumb thing is it did work with doc & PNG. so I have nu clue why that is.